# WooCommerce Remove Extra Zero in 3 Decimal

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, decimal

I'm using 3 decimals so my price's seen as:
"$20.000" , "$20.050" , "$20.055"

I have search about removing zero decimals, and found this one:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', 'wc_hide_trailing_zeros', 10, 1 );
function wc_hide_trailing_zeros( $trim ) {
    // set to false to show trailing zeros
    return true;
}
```

However, it is not working properly. Because It is only removing .000 decimals. ($20.000 to $20)
In addition, I want to just remove an extra 0 decimal from the last decimal segment.

For example;
"$20.000" to "$20.00"
"$20.050" to "$20.05"
"$20.055" will not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above filter (which returns `true`) triggers the execution of [`wc_trim_zeros()` function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/wc-formatting-functions.php#L217), which indeed removes zeros only if the price has only 0 decimals.

What you need is to use the [`formatted_woocommerce_price` hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/wc-formatting-functions.php#L578) instead.

The below filter will cut all trailing zeroes:

```php
add_filter('formatted_woocommerce_price', function($formatted_price, $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator) {
    // Need to trim 0s only if we have the decimal separator present.
    if (strpos($formatted_price, $decimal_separator) !== false) {
        $formatted_price = rtrim($formatted_price, '0');
        // After trimming trailing 0s, it may happen that the decimal separator will remain there trailing... just get rid of it, if it's the case.
        $formatted_price = rtrim($formatted_price, $decimal_separator);
    }
    return $formatted_price;
}, 10, 4);
```

**UPDATE:** the below code will only cut a trailing zero if it's the 3rd and last decimal:

```php
add_filter('formatted_woocommerce_price', function($formatted_price, $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator) {
    // Need to trim 0s only if we have the decimal separator present.
    if (strpos($formatted_price, $decimal_separator) !== false) {
        $formatted_price = preg_replace('/^(\d+' . preg_quote($decimal_separator, '/' ) . '\d{2})0$/', "$1", $formatted_price);
    }
    return $formatted_price;
}, 10, 4);
```

Disclaimer: code not tried out, written directly in the answer box.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The third argument of `add_filter()` is the priority, not the number of arguments. I have updated the code snippet accordingly.

Comment: It only makes $20 from $20.000, when the decimal separator is set to . (dot).

Comment: Done, but $20.000 became $20.

Thanks for
$20.050 became $20.05. Just one problem left

Comment: This one is good but, I prefer $20.00 (decimals to seen)

Comment: If you want 2 decimals to appear, why are you using 3 decimals for your prices?

Comment: because some product prices are $20.055

Comment: Updated answer with code which removes only a 3rd and last decimal 0.